# Remove borders, center a pgfplot both vertically and horizontally and fill the available space

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, border

I would like to create a memory card game for my pupils and generate quadratic cards of 6cm width and height which are then embedded in a master file which puts the cards into a grid.

A single card could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Input format
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=6cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis equal,
                    xtick distance=5,
                    ytick distance=5,
                    xmin=-11,xmax=11,
                    ymin=-11,ymax=11,
                    grid=both,
                    axis lines=middle,
                    minor tick num=4,
                    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                    axis line style={->},
                    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
                    xlabel={$x$},
                    ylabel={$y$},
                    ]
                    \addplot[no marks,blue,-] expression[domain=-10:10,samples=100]{2*x+3};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

As the card is quadratic and the x and y range are of the same length (-11 to 11 each), I'd expect the plot to be quadratic as well, but it is not: The x axis is made longer than the y axis for some reason, so the top and bottom borders are bigger than the left and right border. Also the plot is not horizontally centered although I'm using the center environment. Here is how it looks like:

[image: The output of the code example above]

Hints on what I am doing wrong are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you are graphing `2x+3`, so why would you expect the plot to be quadratic (and not linear)?

Comment: Only part answer, hence comment: `axis equal` doesn't set the size of the axis box. Remove the `\resizebox` and add `scale only axis, width=0.9\linewidth, height=0.9\linewidth,` to the `axis` options.

Comment: @Dan: I guess, my choice of words was quite poor, I referred to the looks of the coordinate system, not the function type.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks, I went with copy&pasting Dan's answer for now but I will have a more detailed look at both of your proposals to better understand how it works as soon as time permits!

Comment: The TeX.SE website it is a great community instead of PSE :-))))+1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the axes actually equal we need to use `axis equal image` instead of `axis equal`, and add a `\nointerlineskip` before `\vspace` to properly center vertically. Removing some spurious spaces at the end of lines fixes the horizontal alignment, and changing the domain and range to [-12,12] instead of [-11,11] avoids a rounding error within `pgfplots` from not drawing the final y grid line (which occurs when we switch to `axis equal image`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Input format
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=6cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{center}
        \nointerlineskip%<--
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis equal image,%<--
                    xtick distance=5,
                    ytick distance=5,
                    xmin=-12,xmax=12,%<--
                    ymin=-12,ymax=12,%<--
                    grid=both,
                    axis lines=middle,
                    minor tick num=4,
                    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                    axis line style={->},
                    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
                    xlabel={$x$},
                    ylabel={$y$},
                    ]
                    \addplot[no marks,blue,-] expression[domain=-12:12,samples=100]{x^2-5*x};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}%<--
        }%<--
        \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's mysterious, I cannot find any spaces after any of the code lines but for some reason my code messes up the horizontal centering even if I make it looks like yours identically, while if I copy&paste yours it works. But I'm quite in a hurry lately so I guess, I will have another look into it at a later point.

Comment: @Photon That is strange. Make sure you have a `%` at the direct end of the `\end{tikzpicture}` and the following line as well as the `\resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{` line.